# Onscroll keeps triggering function even with false if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm using onscroll to call my function to play the video, but I only want it to trigger the function only once. I even put conditional for it so it will only happen once but its not working. Any idea?(fixed with three =)

I also get `play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first` on my staging site on fresh page load.

```js
window.onscroll = scrollfunc;

function scrollfunc() {
    if (document.getElementById("vidhero").style.display = "none") {
        document.getElementById("vidhero").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("vidhero").play();
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h1>The video element</h1>

<video id="vidhero" width="320" height="240" style="display:none" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<div style="height: 100vh"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `if` condition is an assignment and will always be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use === for comparison

```
window.onscroll = scrollfunc;

function scrollfunc() {
    if (document.getElementById("vidhero").style.display === "none") {
        document.getElementById("vidhero").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("vidhero").play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is Difference between `=`, `==`, and `===` in JavaScript

`=` is used for assigning values to a variable in JavaScript.

`==` is used for comparison between two variables irrespective of the datatype of variable.

`===` is used for comparison between two variables but this will check strict type, which means it will check datatype and compare two values.

and `=` is Used for Assigning Something and `==` & `===` are used for comparison, So in your `if` statement you have to use comparison Operator

```
if (document.getElementById("vidhero").style.display == "none")
```